# Unable to set the Min Date

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
 var todaysDate = new Date(); // Gets today's date
  
  // Max date attribute is in "YYYY-MM-DD".  Need to format today's date accordingly
  
  var year = todaysDate.getFullYear();                      // YYYY
  var month = ("0" + (todaysDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);    // MM
  var day = ("0" + (todaysDate.getDate()+3)).slice(-2);         // DD

  var minDate = (year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day); // Results in "YYYY-MM-DD" for today's date 
  
  // Now to set the MIN date value for the calendar to be today's date
  document.getElementById("dateField").setAttribute("min", minDate);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="dateField">
```

I am trying to set the disable the 3 upcoming days in in HTML date picker with a gap of today to 3 days. I am able to achieve this except if its 30th of March today, it has to go for the next month. in that case all dates are enabled. if its 25th of march it works fine. the upcoming dates are disabled. Where I am making the mistake. My code snippet is below.

```
  var todaysDate = new Date(); // Gets today's date
  
  // Max date attribute is in "YYYY-MM-DD".  Need to format today's date accordingly
  
  var year = todaysDate.getFullYear();                      // YYYY
  var month = ("0" + (todaysDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);    // MM
  var day = ("0" + (todaysDate.getDate()+3)).slice(-2);         // DD

  var minDate = (year +"-"+ month +"-"+ day); // Results in "YYYY-MM-DD" for today's date 
  
  document.getElementById("dateField").setAttribute("min", minDate);
```

Also, is it possible just in case if I want to disable weekends from the upcoming three days? Thanks very much.

Edited as per Tiago's Answer

```
  Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
      var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
      return date;
  }

  var date = new Date();

  console.log(date.addDays(3));
  var dist = date.addDays(3) 
  
  var year = dist.getFullYear();
  var month = dist.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = dist.getDate();

  var distdate = (year +'/'+ month +'/'+ day);
  console.log(distdate);

  document.getElementById("dateField").setAttribute("min", distdate );
```

Now I am getting the exact date when the date is added except it is not getting set as min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I did it.

I converted the extra dates into milliseconds, added it to today's date and made a `new Date Instance` from that.

You should learn about [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart). It fills up the string to the required length 1st argument, with whatever is passed into the 2nd argument

```js
const addDate = 3; //Converted these extra days to milliseconds and added it to today's date
const min = new Date(Date.now() +  (addDate * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
const year = min.getFullYear();
const month = (min.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
const day = min.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');

const minDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`; // Results in "YYYY-MM-DD" for today's date 

// Now to set the MIN date value for the calendar to be today's date
document.getElementById("dateField").setAttribute("min", minDate);
document.getElementById("minText").innerText = `Min Date: ${minDate}`;
```

```css
input[type=date]:valid {
  border-color: green;
}

input[type=date]:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="dateField" required>
<span id="minText"></span>
```

Comment: its simple and very understandable. But when you set it to HTML min attribute, no changes at all.

Comment: I will add CSS so if it is invalid you'll see the style

Comment: No Mola, the thing is if its within 3 days, it should disable the dates. it shouldn't allow you to select the disabled date at all.

Comment: That's why I want to add the HTML datepicker min attribute which makes disabling the dates.

Comment: So the allowed dates start from the next three days. except when its a new month?

Comment: Like from today till 18th should be disabled

Comment: correct. example if its march 30, the next 3 should be disabled. so April 2 will be allowed.

Comment: Will past dates before today be allowed? Like 13th or 12th

Comment: Past dates are not a concern Mola. it can be allowed or not allowed that's fine. The only concern is future dates.

Comment: You can check the snippet now

Comment: I am working on too. Wherever I try its a dead end. Changed the date format, as Tiago's answer tried the addDays method but it is not updating the MIN date attribute.

Comment: You're the best Mola.Thanks. I am working on how to skip the count of weekends.

Comment: Okay then... Good Luck. Don't forget to upvote and mark as the correct answer:D

Comment: I have checked padStart. instead of that I was trying ("0" + todaysDate.getDate()).slice(-2); I found out what both does. Your logic with padstart is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Cool... Glad you like that too

Comment: Thanks. is there any logic you aware in order to exclude the weekends from these disabled dates Mola? I mean if there is a weekend falls on within 3 days, it should be skipped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229935/discussion-between-a-mola-and-roshan-zaid).

Comment: @RoshanZaid Let us continue this [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230959/discussion-between-a-mola-and-roshan-zaid)

Answer (score 0):

`var day = ("0" + (todaysDate.getDate()+3)).slice(-2);` returns `34` if today is `30th Mar`

In this case, you can use `setDate` function of Date object to calculate the `minDate` value:

```
var minDate = new Date(); // Gets today's date
minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 3); // right here
// update min setting
document.getElementById("dateField").min = todaysDate.toISOString();
```

Comment: I tried this hoangdv, I am unable to see any changes.